# warning: assignment makes point from integer without cast

Tags: c, warnings

So I'm getting this warning in the last line of this block of code I wrote.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)   
{
 while(1) {
char buffer[400];
char str;

if(strcmp(argv[1],"start") == 0 )
    { printf("myshell: process has started \n");
            int i=0;
            while (str = strtok(buffer," ") == NULL) {          
            argv[i] = str;  //**This line causes the warning!
```

Is it because of how I declare str? Is that incorrect? Thank you!

As the title suggests, the warning is *warning: assignment makes point from integer without cast*.

Comment: Post the error please.

Comment: You're assigning a `char` to a `char*`. And that shouldn't be the only warning/error you get in this. The previous line is just as bad, and doesn't do what you think it does. You're missing a set of parens.

Comment: @WhozCraig How can I fix this? I tried making char str into char *str but that's not it. Also, what makes you say about the more errors? I'm compiling my code and it's the only one I'm getting, should I be concerned?

Comment: @user3295674 just because it compiles doesn't mean it is correct. Ex: the condition in your while-clause. It is assigning the expression `strtok(buffer, " ") == NULL` to a `char` variable. It is *not* assigning `strtok(buffer, " ")` to a `char*`, then testing for `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how this could result in a cast error but I do see an error in your code.  The first call to strtok initializes the token'izer since you pass it a buffer.  The second call, assuming you want it to find the next token, should have a null value instead of the same buffer.

[Look at this example...](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

So what you want is:

```
...
int i=0;
str = strtok(buffer, " ");
do {          
    argv[i] = str;  //**This line causes the warning!
    ...
} while (str = strtok(NULL, " ") != NULL);
```

Comment: ...you also need to fix the "char str;" to "char* str" as WhozCriag mentions.

Comment: Would it need extra parenthesis around (str = strok(NULL, " ")) in the last line? Also, would this also work?                int i=0;
                str = strtok(buffer, " ");
                while (str  == NULL) {      
                argv[i] = str;
                i = i+1;
                }

Comment: Yes and no.  "while (str == NULL) {..." would never enter the loop assuming the buffer had at least one space.  The first call to strtok returns a pointer to the first string, not null.  So I think you mean "while (str != NULL) {..."

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of `strtok()` is `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);`, the return value of `strtok()` is `char *`, therefore the type of `str` should be `char *`.

What is more, `str = strtok(buffer," ") == NULL` means `str = (strtok(buffer," ") == NULL)`, probably not what you want, I guess you mean `(str = strtok(buffer," ")) == NULL`.